# Html.ImageGetter

Tags: html, android

Can any one help me out how to use Html.ImageGetter to dispaly images using html image src tag ? and example or good tutorial

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To get images from the application resources first in the text file one inserts an html image tag like this:

```
<img src="my_image">
```

Note that "my_image" is just a name of a drawable not a path. Then use this code to diplay the text with images in TextView

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(myText, new ImageGetter() {
   @Override public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
      Drawable drawFromPath;
      int path =
            myActivity.this.getResources().getIdentifier(source, "drawable",
               "com.package...");
      drawFromPath = myActivity.this.getResources().getDrawable(path);
      drawFromPath.setBounds(0, 0, drawFromPath.getIntrinsicWidth(),
         drawFromPath.getIntrinsicHeight());
      return drawFromPath;
   }
}, null));
```

If the source in the img tag is misspelled the applicaiton will crash because the method will fail to find the drawable, so more code can be added to prevent this...

Comment: So we should be MORE careful about image name for example NOT flower.jpg it should be flower

Answer (score 7):

Here is the same as the accepted answer, but as a top level class (which is nicer if you want to use it from different places):

```
public class ResourceImageGetter implements ImageGetter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ResourceImageGetter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
        Resources resources = mContext.getResources();
        int identifier = resources.getIdentifier(source, "drawable", mContext.getPackageName());
        Drawable res = resources.getDrawable(identifier);
        res.setBounds(0, 0, res.getIntrinsicWidth(), res.getIntrinsicHeight());
        return res;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The answer from kape123 certainly helped me.  I was so nearly there.

The bit that's easy to miss is the call to **setBounds** on the Drawable.
The Html.ImageGetter help documentation also provides a clue when it says:

*Make sure you call setBounds() on your Drawable if it doesn't already have its bounds set.*

Comment: The slightly aggravating part is how they don't exactly tell you *how* to do so. Why it does not default to the intrinsic values is also beyond me.

Comment: I had the same problem. ie not having set the bounds. Just a thought, couldn't they throw an exception so that we can figure this out sooner?

Answer (score 1):

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlToSetAsText, new ImageGetter() {                 
    @Override
    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
        String path = "/sdcard/" + source;
        Drawable bmp = Drawable.createFromPath(path);
        bmp.setBounds(0, 0, bmp.getIntrinsicWidth(), bmp.getIntrinsicHeight());

        return bmp;
    }
}, null));
```

Comment: This works. But the image gets cropped. Any solution for that ?