# Android add image to webview from a drawable

Tags: android, html

I'd like something:

```
s="
<body>

<img src='"+R.drawable.picture+"'>

</body>";
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Check out the accepted answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792604/html-imagegetter), regarding Html.ImageGetter.
They do exactly what you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [@Android display /res/viewable in WebView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630829/android-display-res-viewable-in-webview)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can only do such a thing if our image is inside your `/assets` folder. Also, you must load your html with a baseUrl that's inside your assets folder.

You can use `WebView.loadUrl()` or `WebView.loadDataWithBaseURL()`:

> webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/file.html");

or

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", "<img src='file.jpg' />", "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

(file.jpg should be inside your assets folder)

Comment: `webView.loadDataWithBaseURL` can load images from drawables. just replace `"file:///android_asset/"` with `"file:///android_res/drawable/"`

Comment: @JonasAlves: Do you know how to do the webview.loadUrl trick with an Android Resource Drawable? Something like `<img src="file:///android/Resources/drawable/ic_menu_info_details.png"\>`? I don't know which is the path to the system resource drawables.

Comment: Even though I read this a few times I wrongly assumed the "most load your html with a baseUrl that's inside your assets folder" part was only needed if you wanted to use a relative path for the src attribute.  Turns out, for whatever weird reasons (security?), this is actually required.  Using full URLs for the src is not enough.

Comment: This is the only working variant with TAPI 26 for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 51):

After some experimenting I found that the following HTML worked on Android 2.3.1 (but not on older versions):

```
<img src="file:///android_res/drawable/example.png"/>
```

The really cool part is that the image file was actually in the directory `drawable-hdpi` but the resource manager provides the image in the standard directory `drawable`.

Comment: Hi there!
Your solution isn't works in table:( :
  <tr>
   <td><img src="file:///android_res/drawable/terkep.png" style="float:left;"></td>
  </tr>

Comment: I just tested it again with table. It works fine on Android 2.3.1. Did you check the API version of your Project in Eclipse?

Comment: Is it working higher version than 2.3.1 for my case its not working am using 4.2.3

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
 web_object.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_res/drawable/", "<img src='test.jpg' />", "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

no need to make seprate html file

Answer (score 1):

Set Image Width 100%.

```
wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_res/drawable/", "<img src='"+ url + "' style='width:100%' />", "text/html", "utf-8", null); 
    wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    wv.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
```