# How to set a background image for android Webview?

Tags: android

I wish to show my text as in justified format, for this purpose i used **webview** instead of **textview**. Here my problem is i wish to add background image for my **webview**. The text content are in my `string.xml`. i used the following code,

```
 <string name="link"> <![CDATA[
     <html>
 <head></head>
 <body style="text-align:justify;color:white;background-color:black;">

// content 
  </body>
</html>

    ]]>
    </string>
```

in this code i set background color as black, instead of that i wish to add an .jpg or .png image. How can i modify this code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534043/android-add-image-to-webview-from-a-drawable

Comment: Why do you want to use WebView instead of TextView ? [try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292575/android-textview-justify-text)

Comment: in text view, the text (here i used a paragraph) is not justify, that's why i'm using webview.

Comment: WebViews does not have background attribute, however you can implement a RelativeLayout and put an ImageView over the Webview and set the a transparency with alpha so it doesnt disturbs the content of the Webview, also consider it putting it attribute clickable to false for the ImageView and you should be all set.

Answer (score 2):

at frist you should put your image in res/drawable.
then change your code

```
<body style='text-align:justify' background="file:///android_res/drawable/a1.jpg" >
```

Answer (score 2):

For that you have to `set background image in xml`

```
           <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:scrollbars="none" />
```

After Declaring in activity you have to `set transparent background color`.

```
            WebView  webView= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
            webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```