# Speed up zoom feature in ImageView

Tags: android, c++, image-scaling, zooming

I'm currently dealing with really big images (7-10mb) that cannot be resized or compressed for multiple reasons.

Now, the idea is to show them in a custom ImageView that enables the user to do the double-tap zoom, pinch to zoom, etc.

I used this library for the job: https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView

I've tried also other libraries but every other library is still really slow. Can someone give me some pointers/suggestion to make it faster (even writing my own C++ implentation)?

I'm a bit lost with all this "Matrix", "flig", "scale" thing and I have no idea of what I should touch to make it faster. If you know also other faster libraries (or how to use the custom Android implementation, that works really fast) it would be great.

Comment: How large are they pixel-wise? Can you upload them to GLES textures?

Comment: sorry, what is GLES textures? Btw, they are 3680x3288, 6.4MB and cannot be resized or scaled.

Comment: On most devices, OpenGL-ES textures can be up to 4096x4096, though some low-end devices might be limited to 2048x2048. GLES can handle the scaling (and rotation, and whatever else you might want to do). Your images might be 6.4MB on disk, but they're 46MB in memory (assuming 32 bits per pixel), because they must be uncompressed before displayed; manipulating that much data in software is not going to be fast, so it's best to let the GPU do it.

Comment: and how can I do to make the GPU to handle it?

Comment: You would need to learn a bit of OpenGL-ES, which comes with a bit of a learning curve. You can find some examples in Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika), e.g. "texture from camera" shows scaling and rotation of live Camera input. You would need to upload your image to a texture with `glTexImage2D()` and then display it, rather than receiving data from the Camera. You can see an example of that in `TextureUploadActivity#runTextureTest()` (which is an off-screen benchmark); between the two examples I think you have all the pieces you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using the DeepZoom feature of the Ion library?

https://github.com/koush/ion

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yIMltNEAKZY

If you don't want to to use opengl, or the above library does not work, you can also try playing with the http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapRegionDecoder.html class. That is, keep track of "where" the user is (the viewport & zoom level) and decode that region off the main thread, pushing it into a canvas each time the user changes the input.

Comment: this works like charm, really thank you! :) exactly what I needed

Answer (score 5):

Try a library called openCV or use it in matlab and then port the code into c/c++ for the image enhancement

Comment: it's not only enhancement, since it's not a "one-shot" zoom.. it's the whole zooming feature connected to gestures, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You could try manually implementing "mipmaps" -- different sizes of the same image, and then just use the most appropriately sized image for displaying....  thus when zoomed out, you'll be manipulating a relatively small image (but will still get the full detail of the large one when zoomed in).

Comment: but it would still be slow with full zoom images, am I right? It's slow moving on the image too, not only the zoom :(

Comment: True. I guess you could split the image into smaller tiles and just display those (doing the math to line them up)...

Answer (score 2):

Try a library called [PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView). When used together with [picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/), i was able to achieve Onlick functionality enabling the user to click a smaller image and have it pop up the full image on a custom view complete with zoom functionality..It's really easy to implement

Comment: thanks but it's too slow this one too. I keep getting:

" Skipped 82 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread."

Any other idea? :(

Answer (score 2):

One way of solving it is by using a WebView, which has support for panning, pinch-zooming etc. I think that image quality may be an issue though.

[android-local-image-in-webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127696/android-local-image-in-webview)

[android-add-image-to-webview-from-a-drawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534043/android-add-image-to-webview-from-a-drawable)

etc.
You can also generate and load the html dynamically

Comment: actually it seems a good idea. Although I can't undersand why on the browser it's just super fast and on the webview it still lags a bit (a lot better than the other solutions though). Any idea?

Comment: Sorry, no, can't say why it's slower.

Answer (score 0):

In TouchImageView.java class DoubleTapZoom set a lower or higher value for ZOOM_TIME

```
private class DoubleTapZoom implements Runnable {
 ......
 private static final float ZOOM_TIME = 500 //(lower - faster)
 ......
```