# Extract DeepZoom feature out of Ion

Tags: android, deepzoom

After asking help about a zooming feature for big images ( [Speed up zoom feature in ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32142204/speed-up-zoom-feature-in-imageview) ) Ashton Engberg replies with the great Ion library that allows you to use the Deep Zoom feature.

Really a good library, although for multiple reasons (mainly because the architecture of my app is already fixed and really hard to change) I want only the deep zoom feature and not all the connection stuff.

Anyone could help me to isolate that feature from everything else? Until now my efforts were pointless, even for building the Ion library.

Any hint, even really small, is appreciated.

Comment: Why not use something like [this library](https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view) instead?

Comment: I love you. I do. Please make an answer with this response so I can give you the accepted answer :) really thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Android Arsenal](http://android-arsenal.com/) is your friend.

(unless you're a huge fan of another Premier League team and have an aversion to anything with "Arsenal" in the name, in which case the Android Arsenal is not your friend, but still is a useful site)

[Searching the Arsenal for `zoom`](http://android-arsenal.com/search?q=zoom) turns up a few libraries offering pinch-to-zoom capabilities. Of those, the one that seems closest to "Deep Zoom", off the cuff, is [Subsampling Zoom Image View](https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view), in that it is designed to deal with very large images. Though if your image is already pre-tiled, [TileView](https://github.com/moagrius/TileView) may be a better choice.

Comment: my image is not already tiled, so the subsampling zoom image view simply works great. Even better of Ion. Thank you again for your help and the pointer to Android Arsenal, really appreciated :)