# Use drawable inside HTML Page

Tags: android, android-webview

I am developing an application in which I am loading an HTML page inside Webview. I am to use an image in that HTML which is inside my drawable. How would I give path to that image inside HTML.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534043/android-add-image-to-webview-from-a-drawable

Comment: That solution didn't work file:///android_res/drawable/example.png

Comment: @NileshRathod That solution didn't work file:///android_res/drawable/example.png