# Android - Class Html - fromHtml - How does it work?

Tags: android, html, xml, class, parsing

I'm using Html.fromHtml to get the contents of a description tag (in a feed XML) and it works fine

Description tag:

```
<description><![CDATA[<div class="K2FeedIntroText"><p><img style="margin: 10px; float: left;" alt="block curta" src="http://loc.grupolusofona.pt/images/stories/destaques/block%20curta.jpg" height="110" width="120" />Quatro Horas Descalço é o nome da curta-metragem, realizada por Ico Costa, que se estreia mundialmente no 7.º Festival Internacional de Cinema de Roma, nos dias 12 e 13 de novembro, em competição no Cinema XXI.</p>
```

]]>

But as I go look into the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html) it says:

`Returns displayable styled text from the provided HTML string. Any <img> tags in the HTML will display as a generic replacement image which your program can then go through and replace with real images.`

So my question is: how can i do what it says there "which your program can then go through and replace with the real image" ?

I know how to get the img url via RegEx using a Pattern, i just wanted to know how can i use the class to "go through and replace it with the image"

Please say something if i was unclear and ill try to explain it better.

**EDIT:**

Well, i'm trying to implement this in a simple rss reader (and trying to keep it as simple as possible code-wise)

I'm using a DOM Parser and i'm using a `map = HashMap<String, Spanned>` to store the values of each child node, along with a `KEY`:

`map.put(KEY_DESC, Html.fromHtml(parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC)));`

In the comments of the answer i found a useful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7442725/1779071) from which i created a new Class (URLImageParser) and tried to use it like so:

`map.put(KEY_DESC, htmlSpan);`

Where `htmlSpan` would be the result of:

```
this.textView = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.textview);
URLImageParser p = new URLImageParser(textView, this);
Spanned htmlSpan = Html.fromHtml(html, p, null);
textView.setText(htmlSpan);
```

I also created a `android:visibility="gone"` TextView just in case it needed to store the values in a TextView (maybe i interpreted it wrong)

My original thought was that `htmlSpan` was of the type `Spanned` so it would fit in my HashMap just fine.

For uploading to ListView i'm using a `SimpleAdapter` like so:

```
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems, R.layout.linhafeed, 
            new String[] { KEY_TITLE, KEY_DESC, KEY_PUBDATE, KEY_LINK },
            new int[] { R.id.title, R.id.desc, R.id.pub, R.id.link });
```

Where `menuItems` is `ArrayList<HashMap<String,Spanned>>`

Something i got wrong here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Html.fromHtml(...)` will replace any `<img ... />` tag with an `ImageSpan` and a special ['object replacement character' (\uFFFC)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffc/index.htm).

To get the actual image to show up, it looks like there are two options:

- implement an [`ImageGetter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.ImageGetter.html) that returns the image to display as a `Drawable`. If I recall correctly, this won't allow you to offload the image loading to a different thread, because it expects the result to be returned right away. Hence, this should suffice for local resources (and probably also any assets in a device's local storage, provided there are no potentially long-running operations required; i.e. scaling, cropping, applying effects etc).
- do a second pass over the `Spanned` result and replace any `\uFFFC` occurrences. You should be able to get the source (url) of the image from every `ImageSpan` using the `getSource()` method. Unfortunately, it doesn't look there are any setters to update the `Drawable` once loaded, so I'm guessing you may need to replace the `ImageSpan` with a new one, passing in the loaded image in the constructor.

A third alternative, which may be a bit more heavy-weight than above, is to use a `WebView` rather than a `TextView`. That way you don't have to deal with any of the image loading yourself, as it's built into the widget.

Comment: On the first point, the ImageGetter, let's suppose i'd return the image as a `Drawable`. I would have to put it in an `ImageView` or could i put it in the place of the `object replacement character` and how ?

Comment: @jsfrocha: No, you'd just return the `Drawable` that will be displayed inside the `ImageSpan` - no need to use an `ImageView`, which can't be placed inside a `TextView` anyhow. [Here's an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4821151/1029225). It appears someone here on SO came up with an [`ImageGetter` that loads your images in the background](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7442725/1029225) by the way - probably worth checking out.

Comment: So i tried [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7424512/1779071) this solution by @momo and it compiles, runs, and doesnt mid-crash, but no image appears. It probably has something to do with where i'm implementing it. Maybe i should've mentioned it in the original question.. gonna edit it..

Comment: Any ideas on how to do this ?

Comment: Based on the snippets given, I can't really tell where it's going wrong. I'm guessing it might be because of the way you create the spans - I'd try moving the whole `Html.fromHtml(...)` part into a custom adapter. However, perhaps better is to rethink your approach. It looks like you're trying to populate a list with an thumbnail image with some text next to it. Then why not use an adapter with `ImageView` and `TextView` as row layout? This is a much more standard pattern and there'll be heaps of resources around to guide you.

Comment: Yeah, i guess i'm going with the custom adapter approach and i'll try to implement the `ImageGetter` that way.

Comment: If you're going to use a custom adapter and work with `ImageView`s for the images then there's no need for an actual `ImageGetter` anymore. Obviously you'll still want something that retrieves the images in the background, which is usually called an 'image loader'. A commonly used one is [Android Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader). It should require minimal effort to get to work.

Comment: Actually what i really wanted was to figure out how `ImageGetter` works, as an actual alternative to image loaders.