# How to send emojis (image, smileys) in a chat or message app in Android?

Tags: android, image, email, textview, sms

how to send text and emoticon/image(not the default emojis,images in asset folder) written together in a edittext to send message and chat as it is appearing in that edittext.

p.s I am sending those images in mail or message body.

I am trying a following code :

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements KeyClickListener {

private static final int NO_OF_EMOTICONS = 54;

private ListView chatList;
private View popUpView;
private ArrayList<Spanned> chats;
private ChatListAdapter mAdapter;

private LinearLayout emoticonsCover;
private PopupWindow popupWindow;

private int keyboardHeight; 
private EditText content;
CustomizeDialogWithAction customizeDialog = null; 
private LinearLayout parentLayout;

private boolean isKeyBoardVisible;
private boolean keyicon = true;


Bitmap bitmap;
Bitmap temp;
Uri URI = null;
ImageView image;

public String body;

private Bitmap[] emoticons;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = 
                new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }

    chatList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.chat_list);     

    parentLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.list_parent);

    emoticonsCover = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.footer_for_emoticons);

    popUpView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.emoticons_popup, null);

    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);

    bitmap = EmoticonsGridAdapter.mainBitMap;

    // Setting adapter for chat list
    chats = new ArrayList<Spanned>();
    mAdapter = new ChatListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), chats);
    chatList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    chatList.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (popupWindow.isShowing())
                popupWindow.dismiss();  
            return false;
        }
    });

    // Defining default height of keyboard which is equal to 230 dip
    final float popUpheight = getResources().getDimension(
            R.dimen.keyboard_height);
    changeKeyboardHeight((int) popUpheight);

    // Showing and Dismissing pop up on clicking emoticons button
    final ImageView emoticonsButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.emoticons_button);
    emoticonsButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (!popupWindow.isShowing()) {

                emoticonsButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.key);

                popupWindow.setHeight((int) (keyboardHeight));

                if (isKeyBoardVisible == true) {
                    emoticonsCover.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);

                } 
                else if (isKeyBoardVisible == false) {

                    emoticonsCover.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);

                }
                popupWindow.showAtLocation(parentLayout, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);

            } else {
                popupWindow.dismiss();
                emoticonsButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.smily_key);
            }
        }
    });
    readEmoticons();
    enablePopUpView();
    checkKeyboardHeight(parentLayout);
    enableFooterView();
}
/**
 * Reading all emoticons in local cache
 */
private void readEmoticons () {

    emoticons = new Bitmap[NO_OF_EMOTICONS];
    for (short i = 0; i < NO_OF_EMOTICONS; i++) {           
        emoticons[i] = getImage((i+1) + ".png");
    }
}
/**
 * Enabling all content in footer i.e. post window
 */
private void enableFooterView() {

    content = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.chat_content);
    content.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (popupWindow.isShowing()) {

                popupWindow.dismiss();

            }
        }
    });
    final Button postButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.post_button);      

    postButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (content.getText().toString().length() > 0) {

                Spanned sp = content.getText();                 
                chats.add(sp);
                content.setText("");                    
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                //                  final Uri uri = Uri.parse(""+sp);




                customizeDialog = new CustomizeDialogWithAction(MainActivity.this);  
                customizeDialog.setTitle(""); 
                customizeDialog.cancelButton.setText("Cancel");
                customizeDialog.cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        customizeDialog.dismiss();  
                    }
                });
                customizeDialog.mailButton.setText("Mail");
                customizeDialog.mailButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        //                          Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        //                          shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
                        //                          shareIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
                        //                          shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
                        //
                        //
                        //                          shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                        //                          startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share via"));

                        Uri bmpUri = getLocalBitmapUri(image);
                        if (bmpUri != null) {
                            // Construct a ShareIntent with link to image
                            Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
                            shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
                            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
                            shareIntent.setType("image/*");
                            // Launch sharing dialog for image
                            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Image"));    
                        } else {
                            // ...sharing failed, handle error
                        }

                        customizeDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                customizeDialog.messageButton.setText("Message");
                customizeDialog.messageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        Uri bmpUri = getLocalBitmapUri(image);
                        if (bmpUri != null) {
                            // Construct a ShareIntent with link to image
                            Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
                            shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
                            shareIntent.putExtra("sms_body", body);
                            shareIntent.setType("image/*");
                            // Launch sharing dialog for image
                            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Image"));    
                        } else {
                            // ...sharing failed, handle error
                        }

                        customizeDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                customizeDialog.show();  

            }
        }
    });
}
public Uri getLocalBitmapUri(ImageView imageView) {
    // Extract Bitmap from ImageView drawable
    Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
    Bitmap bmp = null;
    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable){
        bmp = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
    // Store image to default external storage directory
    Uri bmpUri = null;
    try {
        File file =  new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(  
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "share_image_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
        out.close();
        bmpUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bmpUri;
}
/**
 * Overriding onKeyDown for dismissing keyboard on key down
 */
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (popupWindow.isShowing()) {
        popupWindow.dismiss();
        return false;
    } else {
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
/**
 * Checking keyboard height and keyboard visibility
 */
int previousHeightDiffrence = 0;
private void checkKeyboardHeight(final View parentLayout) {

    parentLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
            new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {

                    Rect r = new Rect();
                    parentLayout.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);

                    int screenHeight = parentLayout.getRootView()
                            .getHeight();
                    int heightDifference = screenHeight - (r.bottom);

                    if (previousHeightDiffrence - heightDifference > 50) {                          
                        popupWindow.dismiss();
                    }
                    previousHeightDiffrence = heightDifference;
                    if (heightDifference > 100) {

                        isKeyBoardVisible = true;
                        changeKeyboardHeight(heightDifference);

                    } else {

                        isKeyBoardVisible = false;

                    }
                }
            });
}
/**
 * change height of emoticons keyboard according to height of actual
 * keyboard
 * 
 * @param height
 *            minimum height by which we can make sure actual keyboard is
 *            open or not
 */
private void changeKeyboardHeight(int height) {

    if (height > 100) {
        keyboardHeight = height;
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, keyboardHeight);
        emoticonsCover.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
}
/**
 * Defining all components of emoticons keyboard
 */
private void enablePopUpView() {

    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) popUpView.findViewById(R.id.emoticons_pager);
    pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);

    ArrayList<String> paths = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (short i = 1; i <= NO_OF_EMOTICONS; i++) {          
        paths.add(i + ".png");
    }

    EmoticonsPagerAdapter adapter = new EmoticonsPagerAdapter(MainActivity.this, paths, this);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Creating a pop window for emoticons keyboard
    popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popUpView, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            (int) keyboardHeight, false);

    TextView backSpace = (TextView) popUpView.findViewById(R.id.back);
    backSpace.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            KeyEvent event = new KeyEvent(0, 0, 0, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL, 0, 0, 0, 0, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENDCALL);
            content.dispatchKeyEvent(event);    
        }
    });
    popupWindow.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDismiss() {
            emoticonsCover.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
        }
    });
}
/**
 * For loading smileys from assets
 */
private Bitmap getImage(String path) {
    AssetManager mngr = getAssets();
    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = mngr.open("emoticons/" + path);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    temp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, null);
    return temp;
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public void keyClickedIndex(final String index) {

    ImageGetter imageGetter = new ImageGetter() {
        public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {    
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(index, ".");
            Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),emoticons[Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()) - 1]);
            d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());

            image.setImageDrawable(d);
            return d;
        }
    };
    Spanned cs = Html.fromHtml("<img src ='"+ index +"'/>", imageGetter, null);        

    int cursorPosition = content.getSelectionStart();       
    content.getText().insert(cursorPosition, cs);

    body = content.getText().toString();

}
```

}

I am sending the data like this(see screenshot):[image: my activity screenshot]

but the emoticon(image) i am sending appears like this(see screenshot).![my activity second image][2]

When i send any image it will apear like this "[obj]". How to solve it please help me.

Comment: Same problem here brother. Did you get any workaround.

Answer (score 7):

As I am creating an `emoji softkeyboard` for all apps like facebook,whats app , etc.

You can send emoticons easily using **Unicode** [here](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode) . save them in a

`Map<Pattern,Integer>` and send them.

These unicode are already implemented on facebook,whats app and they easily behave according.

[**Sending Emoticons using UniCode**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341702/displaying-emoticons-in-android/4302199#4302199)

if you really want to send images from your assets

[then try this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792604/html-imagegetter) .

But i recommend you sending by unicodes because all apps know how to react after recieving these codes.