# create a softkeyboard having symboles in it in android

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, emoji

```
I want to create a keyboard like emojis but i donot know from where i should start?If anyone has any idea or a sample code please let me know.And i also want to add symbols in my keyboard which should be recognisable by every app like facebook,messages(default) and whatsApp.
```

I searched a lot but found nothing so please help me if anybody can!If any one provide me a sample code or having a link ,where I can learn from scratch please send me, i will be very thankful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be multiple possibilities of your questions.

1. [**Want to create a custom Emoji softKeyboard**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480715/how-to-develop-a-soft-keyboard-for-android)
2. Want to create a app specific softkeyboard [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896939/android-app-specific-soft-keyboard) and [this](http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm)
3. Want to just send emoji without creating softkeyboard

[How to send emojis (image, smileys) in a chat or message app in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23134619/how-to-send-emojis-image-smileys-in-a-chat-or-message-app-in-android/27183457#27183457)